# Uploading files to S3 via intermediate server in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, amazon-s3

I have a made a service for S3 through which multiple applications can upload files through S3.

The link to upload file is something like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/s3/add
```

From one of my applications, I am trying to do something like this:

```
public function upload(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
       $curl_add_file = curl_init('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/s3/add');
       $file = $request->file('file_image');

       $data['doc']  = $file;

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type:multipart/form-data'
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost:8000/api/v1/s3/add");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        echo curl_exec($request);
}
```

On the S3 Service Controller, I am doing like this:

```
public function saveToS3(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $request->hasFile('doc') {
        //Code to save on S3
    } else {
        //echo 'false';
    }
}
```

It always goes to else statement and returns false.

When I debug what $request contains, it gives me a temporary location something like this as value for doc: '\opt\lamp\temp\Ph6FG7n'

What am I missing out here? 
How can I send files using curl to another service?

I am using Service for S3 here is not all my apps would be on Laravel; some are using Core PHP.

Comment: Could you show your request? It seems you send file as string `doc=filepath` not the file content

Comment: Why don't use the storage::put method?https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem